# Can the flock of 'Taken' ravens be 'killed' or destroyed?

Tags: alan-wake

Can the flock of 'Taken' ravens be 'killed' or destroyed (i.e. the flock won't return to attack you again) if a certain number of ravens in the flock are killed? Or is the flock merely driven away if you attack them with light?

I would like to know because I'm wondering if I could stand and fight them,  or if I'll just have to watch out for them and try to defend myself while traveling to the next area, where they'll stop attacking.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they can be destroyed. Shine your flashlight on them and they will die eventually.

Because they flee the light and can't be damaged while far away, it is a good idea to point the flashlight somewhere else until they are close, then turn it on them.

Comment: Just to clarify: You're talking about the whole flock (the whole flock can be destroyed or prevented from attacking again) and not the individual ravens, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The flock will explode when the circle around your flashlight's beam becomes small enough enough.